# Is there a way to put conditionals in functions?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

Is there a way to make something conditional in a function? For example

```
setblock 5 10 5 air
tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"Placed!"}]} # <--- Make this command conditional (only runs if the setblock worked)
give @p diamond_helmet # <-- this runs anyway
```

I know how to do certain things conditionally such as running a command if a creeper is there:

```
execute @e[type=creeper,c=1] ~~~ execute @p ~~~ say Hi!
```

but for things other than single entity detection I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: Not in a straight forward way, no; this is a missing feature from functions.  I think you should be able to store the result of the `setblock` in the scoreboard and `execute` based on that.

Comment: @MBraedley how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure and don't have the time right now to research it, hence why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @MBraedley thanks for your help, but that is not at all possible to my knowledge. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I didn't realize you were in Bedrock Edition.  It's missing the commands necessary to do this, namely the updated execute command and the old stats command.  It is possible in Java Edition though.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a workaround, but it does the job:

```
setblock 5 10 5 air
execute @p 5 10 5 detect ~ ~ ~ air -1 tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"Placed!"}]}
give @p diamond_helmet
```

`-1` is the Block ID. If set to -1 it will work with any Block ID. The execute command basically detects if what the previous setblock command was done.

Comment: This is clever, but this would only work for the `/setblock` command

Comment: Wait; ***wouldn't the -1 just look for any damage value with the ID air? I'm fairly certain only air qualifies for that test.***